# How to make the editor not look for input when none has been entered

Tags: c#

So right now I'm trying to make a game in raw C# but I can't figure out how to stop my code from stopping and looking for input when none has been entered.
its kinda alot btw.

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
static void Main() {
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
string answer;

int Posx = 01;
int Posy = 0;
int x = 100;
string H = x.ToString();
string RA = "Good";
string LA = "Good";
string RL = "Good";
string LL = "Good";
string Chest = "Good";
string Head = "Good";

string[][] b = new string[][] 
{
    new string[]       {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
    new string[] {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"}
};
Console.Clear();
while(true){
    
    
    //____GRAPHICS CODE____\\
    b[Posy][Posx] = "[]";
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[06][01]}{b[06][02]}{b[06][03]}{b[06][04]}{b[06][05]}{b[06][06]}{b[06][07]}{b[06][08]}{b[06][09]}{b[06][10]}{b[06][011]}{b[06][012]}{b[06][013]}{b[06][014]}{b[06][015]}{b[06][016]}{b[06][017]}{b[06][018]}{b[06][019]}{b[06][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[05][01]}{b[05][02]}{b[05][03]}{b[05][04]}{b[05][05]}{b[05][06]}{b[05][07]}{b[05][08]}{b[05][09]}{b[05][10]}{b[05][011]}{b[05][012]}{b[05][013]}{b[05][014]}{b[05][015]}{b[05][016]}{b[05][017]}{b[05][018]}{b[05][019]}{b[05][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[04][01]}{b[04][02]}{b[04][03]}{b[04][04]}{b[04][05]}{b[04][06]}{b[04][07]}{b[04][08]}{b[04][09]}{b[04][10]}{b[04][011]}{b[04][012]}{b[04][013]}{b[04][014]}{b[04][015]}{b[04][016]}{b[04][017]}{b[04][018]}{b[04][019]}{b[04][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[03][01]}{b[03][02]}{b[03][03]}{b[03][04]}{b[03][05]}{b[03][06]}{b[03][07]}{b[03][08]}{b[03][09]}{b[03][10]}{b[03][011]}{b[03][012]}{b[03][013]}{b[03][014]}{b[03][015]}{b[03][016]}{b[03][017]}{b[03][018]}{b[03][019]}{b[03][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[02][01]}{b[02][02]}{b[02][03]}{b[02][04]}{b[02][05]}{b[02][06]}{b[02][07]}{b[02][08]}{b[02][09]}{b[02][10]}{b[02][11]}{b[02][012]}{b[02][013]}{b[02][014]}{b[02][015]}{b[02][016]}{b[02][017]}{b[02][018]}{b[02][019]}{b[02][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[01][01]}{b[01][02]}{b[01][03]}{b[01][04]}{b[01][05]}{b[01][06]}{b[01][07]}{b[01][08]}{b[01][09]}{b[01][10]}{b[01][011]}{b[01][012]}{b[01][013]}{b[01][014]}{b[01][015]}{b[01][016]}{b[01][017]}{b[01][018]}{b[01][019]}{b[01][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[0][01]}{b[0][02]}{b[0][03]}{b[0][04]}{b[0][05]}{b[0][06]}{b[0][07]}{b[0][08]}{b[0][09]}{b[0][10]}{b[0][011]}{b[0][012]}{b[0][013]}{b[0][014]}{b[0][015]}{b[0][016]}{b[0][017]}{b[0][018]}{b[0][019]}{b[0][20]}");
    Console.WriteLine("you are @ type Up Down Left or Right to move in that direction");
    Console.WriteLine("the enemy only moves when you do. the enemies can hide in trees enemies are &");
    Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________stats____________________________________________________________");
    Console.WriteLine($"{H}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Head condition = {Head}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Chest condition = {Chest}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Left Arm condition = {LA}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Right Arm condition = {RA}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Left Leg condition = {LL}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Right Leg condition = {RL}");
    
    
    
    
    
    //____MOVEMENT CODE____\\
    
//This is where it stops and looks for input and I don't want it to


    var KP = Console.ReadKey();
    if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
    {
        if(Posy > 5){
        b[Posy][Posx] = "#";
        Posy = 0;
        } else{
        Posy += 1;
        b[Posy - 1][Posx] = "#";
        }
    }      
    else if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
    {
        if(Posy < 1){
        b[Posy][Posx] = "#";
        Posy = 6;
        } else{
        Posy -= 1;
        b[Posy + 1][Posx] = "#";
        }
    }      
    else if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
    {
        if(Posx < 1){
        b[Posy][Posx] = "#";
        Posx = 20;
        }
        Posx -= 1;
        b[Posy][Posx + 1] = "#";
    }      
    else if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
    {
        if(Posx > 19){
        b[Posy][Posx] = "#";
        Posx = 0;
        }
        Posx += 1;
        b[Posy][Posx - 1] = "#";
    }
    Console.Clear();
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

}
}
`

I tried a different method of fixing it by switching up how I did inputs from the basic console.read to key inputs but this only eliminates the issue of having to press enter.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  `Console.Read...` operations read input from the console.  If that isn't what you want to do, don't use those operations?

Comment: `Console.KeyAvailable` tells you if there is input waiting to be read.

Comment: `Console.Read` returns "The next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be read." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-7.0 You might be able to use that.

Comment: How do I use Console.KeyAvailable because that would fix my problem